# How to repeat single value as many times as other column in Python data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have to create Data frame with two columns in which `df['col1']` rows should repeat as many times as other column `df['col2']`. This should repeat many times depends on list data.

```
Df:
     col1      col2

     Fruit     Apple
     Fruit     Mango
     Fruit     banana
     Place     US
     Place     UK
     Place     France 
     Place     India
```

Where I have data in following format

`List1 =["fruit", "place"]
List2 =[["Apple", "Mango", "Banana"], ["US", "UK", "France", "India"]]`

**Note**: not for loop approach bcs I have 2 million rows

Comment: Please state your effort and the *exact* problem/error you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using numpy.repeat to repeat elements in list1 and itertools.chain.from_iterable to flatten the nested list,

```
list1 =['fruit', 'place']
list2 =[['Apple', 'Mango', 'Banana'], ['US', 'UK', 'France', 'India']]

import itertools
import numpy as np

l1 = np.repeat(np.array(list1), [len(i) for i in list2])
l2 = np.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2)))
pd.DataFrame({'col1':l1, 'col2':l2})



    col1    col2
0   fruit   Apple
1   fruit   Mango
2   fruit   Banana
3   place   US
4   place   UK
5   place   France
6   place   India
```